# Access child canvas element from parent component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas

I am building a app where one can sign with pointer.

I have installed [react-canvas-signature](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-signature-canvas).

Now I need to get signature from the canvas and show it as a popup, and in their Readme files is said that there is a function `toDataURL()`

> toDataURL(mimetype, encoderOptions): base64string, returns the signature image as a data URL

It says they are accessed through API

> API
>   All API methods require a ref to the SignatureCanvas in order to use and are instance methods of the ref. `<SignatureCanvas ref={(ref) => { this.sigCanvas = ref }} />`

However, I am unable to access this function or any function described there.
I have tried to use `useRef()`, `createRef()` but still nothing. Maybe I am just not doing it right.

Please find below parent component without unnecessary lines:

```js
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
import ReactCanvas from 'react-signature-canvas';

interface IProps {}

interface IState {}

export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content-area">
        <ReactCanvas penColor='black' canvasProps={{width: 353, height: 120}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to create ref like so `private myRef = createRef<ReactCanvas>()` and then to use it

```
const canvasRef = this.myRef.current
    if (canvasRef) {
      canvasRef.props.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
    }
```

and it says

> Property 'toDataURL' does not exist on type 'Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

`ref` is in child element like this `<ReactCanvas penColor='black' canvasProps={{width: 353, height: 120}} ref={this.myRef} />`

Can you please show how should I do it, or even a direction/suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: How did you imported react-signature-canvas to TypeScript? It doesn't contain typings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way.

Firstly I needed to create empty object `sigCanvas: any = {}`, next I use it to create ref in the ReactCanvas component `<ReactCanvas minWidth={1} maxWidth={2} canvasProps={{width: 353, height: 120}} ref={(ref) => { this.sigPad = ref }} />` and then I could use it in the functions like so

```
getCanvasImage = () => {
    this.setState({toDataUrl: this.sigPad.getTrimmedCanvas()
      .toDataURL('image/png', 1)})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add image to canvas in `ComponentDidMount` method

```
export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  private canvasRef = createRef<ReactCanvas>();
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.canvasRef.current.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content-area">
        <ReactCanvas
          penColor="black"
          canvasProps={{ width: 353, height: 120 }}
          ref={this.canvasRef}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I tried in my local machine, and it works!